# Auto reboot server every sunday and run a python script in tmux -d

Tags: linux, cron, tmux

I have a server which needs a reboot every Sunday.
I have a python script I want to run in "tmux detached" automatically after each weekly reboot.
How can I automate this?

I guess it's a bash script with cronjob?

I have seen this: https://superuser.com/questions/440015/restore-tmux-session-after-reboot

But I can't get it to work. Maybe I am saving it as a wrong extension or something or maybe it just ain't working since it is 10 years old lol.

I haven't been able to find other resources, why I now ask.

Hopefully some of you are kind enough to help.

In advance, thank you!

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: No, sorry. :( Still want the answer tho, but it's not as important as it was when I asked the question.